# Meaning of "I'm not your friend, buddy", besides the literal meaning

Tags: meaning

Does the expression "I'm not your friend, buddy" have a colloquial meaning?

I've now seen it used twice. I am guessing it has more than just a literal meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a joke that you would say to your friend, to tell them that they are your friends still. It's used when perhaps something has just happened, that might harm your relationship, so you say, "I'm not your friend, buddy", and then you have a good laugh, and then both of you will understand what has passed, is past.

Its origin [is from](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I'm%20not%20your%20friend%2C%20buddy):

> I'm not your friend buddy is an internet phenomenon that was inspired by an episode of "South Park". Usually occurring on message boards, the first person says "I'm not your friend buddy" and the next person will use the use the last word in the first comment as the first word in their comment, and will switch the their last word with either "pal", or "guy". 
>   -I'm not your friend, buddy 
>   -I'm not your buddy, pal 
>   -I'm not your pal, guy 
>   -I'm not your guy, friend 
>   -I'm not your friend, pal 
>   -I'm not your pal, buddy

It's just a play on words, as well as saying the direct opposite of what you actually mean. i.e. first, you say, "I'm not your friend," then you call him "buddy".

Comment: This reminds me of this [Dane Cook bit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkBiQOYgNVk) (starting at about 3:35).  [Not Safe For Work]

Comment: Wasn't this also used in the remake of _Ocean's Eleven_?

Comment: Not exactly, but similar: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0240772/quotes?qt=qt0329558

Comment: [IMDB quote from the South Park episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211261/quotes/qt1010022?mavIsAdult=false&mavCanonicalUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt1211261%2Fquotes) (slightly different order)

Answer (score 6):

The term, and others like it, are a play on stereotypical North American cultures, where in polite conversation you refer to the other person with some platonic term of endearment such as "buddy", "guy", "dude", "pal", "homie", etc, most of which are vernacular synonyms for "friend". The subtext is that the two people talking are angry with each other, and aren't "friends", but are too polite (or habitually inured) to not use the term of endearment at the end of their sentence.

South Park used this to comedic effect in an episode involving Canadians, which is where your phrase probably originated. But, you could envision this happening in many cultures including in the US.