# Meaning and origins of the American slang expression "ad' a boy, shooter!"

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang, dialects

What does the American slang expression *ad' a boy, shooter!* mean? In high school I had an American teacher who would always say this, can't remember which state he was from, I think it's an abbreviation of *what a boy, shooter!*.

He would say this whenever someone would give a correct answer or good reasoning to a problem or question he would have pointed out.

What does the *shooter* part actually mean. Does it imply something sexual such as ejaculation from the penis. Does it imply ejaculation of words from the mouth. Spitting it out, in other words.

I can't describe the amount of fun we all had with this expression, (which was just used, and never explained).

Comment: It is probably [*attaboy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attaboy) that you heard.

Comment: @Mick Since you have effectively answered the question, why not make it into an answer that we can vote on?

Comment: @Spagirl "Attaboy, shooter" may be a fixed phrase with a particular meaning. Anyway, the OP is more interested in the meaning of *shooter*, so I'll refrain. Also, I've just provided a fairly detailed answer on Photography.SE, which took me some time, so I'm rather tired.

Comment: I don't think "shooter" has any significance beyond the immediate context (speaker is impressed by something done by someone he knows as "Shooter"). [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22attaboy+scooter%22) a 1978 instance of ***Attaboy, Scooter!***, where the speaker then goes on to extol Scooter's finer qualities.

Comment: Why would it imply any sort of ejaculation at all? I think that's just your teenage mind which was seeing sex everywhere as teenage minds are wont to do.

Comment: It's funny. Anyways, the Wikipedia page places an emphasizing stress I the first syllable, but I've heated it stressed on the second syllable. Maybe the IPA there needs to be updated with this variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Attaboy* or *thattaboy* or *that a boy* is an informal expression of praise, approval, or encouragement of American origin, first attested 1909. As [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=attaboy) has it:

> *interj.* *Informal* Used to show encouragement or approval to a boy or man:
>
> > Attaboy! That's the way to hit a home run!
>
> [Alteration of *That's the boy!*]

The OED also gives that origin, which seems plausible, though *[that's my boy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/that%27s_my_boy_%28or_girl%29%21)* as an exclamation is easier to find and remains in popular usage.

*Boy* is used in the affectionate or playful sense, and does not necessarily refer to a youth, or even necessarily a male. Still, *attagirl* is a natural alternative for females, attested from the 1920s.

As an actual interjection I rarely hear it except with children or pets, or in fairly informal settings. As a noun referring to a short statement of approbation, it is unexceptional. It is like *kudos* or *cheers* in my idiolect.

---

As to *Shooter*, given your teacher's readiness to use familiar language with students, I would say it is simply a [familiarizing nickname](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334424) intended to demonstrate affection or informality. It may be an obscure reference, or he may simply have liked the sound of it, but it is not attached to any particular region or meaning.

All manner of words are used in this way by all kinds of people. Off the top of my head, you'll find television dialogue where someone is addressed as *champ*, *tiger*, *kiddo*, *chief*, *sport*, *sailor*, *ace*, *amigo*, or *cowboy* — with absolutely zero relationship to their championship, tigrinity, maturity, authority, athleticism, nauticality, aerial lethality, friendship, or … vaquerage? Anyway, in real life I also know people who address everyone as *senator* or *gunner* or *homes* or *bad boy*.

There are no real rules dictated by the language, only by social convention. For instance, some women may not appreciate being called *big fella* or *papa bear*, and *cupcake* or *dreamboat* may be interpreted as diminutive, or insulting, or flirtatious except among very close peers. As tchrist cautions in the other question, these words are therefore fraught and the risk of misunderstanding or insult is extremely high— as we seem to have seen here.

Comment: Yeah, but in an informal setting a humorous word or phrase that puzzles everyone really adds some flavor, laughter, and enthusiasm, besides catching everyone's attention. Thanks for the answer.