# I use "man" referring to male friends...what should I use when talking with a girl?

Tags: colloquialisms, hailnames

Just like I asked in the subject line, I'm pretty lost in this, as I wouldn't know how to say a sentence like the following, speaking with a fem

Comment: By "girl" do you mean a grown-up woman?

Comment: I don’t see a following sentence. I thought you accidentally posted before you were done writing...

Comment: Also “referring to” and “talking with” are *completely* different things.

Comment: "I referred to him as @Jim, when addressing him via the comments". I think the tchrist's answer has nailed it. The question is about "hailnames". As a fairly tolerant woman, I don’t take offence at "man" or "dude" any more than "Miss".

Comment: “A fem” doesn’t mean what you seem to think it means. It’s also quite offensive.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, we may have to assume "cut off mid word" in this case. Never attribute to malice what can be easily explained by technical fault!

Comment: @Pam Yes, I do hope that’s the case. The ‘following sentence’ mentioned is also missing, so it may be the true explanation.

Comment: You can avoid these sorts of problems by just addressing everybody, male or female, as "baby".

Answer (score 3):

Native speakers don't talk with fems. :)

There are certainly speech communities where various sorts of hailnames are used by men to address women with when for whatever reason they don’t want to call them by their given names or using the standard personal pronoun *you*.

Because virtually all of these risk insult, you should probably avoid trying to use any of them even if you ***are*** a native speaker.

And if you are ***not*** a native speaker, then you would do well to heed [this advice about *hailnames*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/334437/2085):

> There are oodles of these, but most of them occur only between men, often young men, in casual situations. Many are strictly regional. Some say something about the age, sex, race, education, or social class of the speaker or the person addressed. Others carry a tone of irony, aggression, or condescension. They impose a faux intimacy if used on someone you don’t know, something many take offence at.
>
> Whenever you address someone by something other than their name or the pronoun you, you risk offending them. Name-calling is risky business indeed.
>
> It is impossible for the non-native to judge the appropriate connotation of these for any given situation. Even for native speakers they risk coming off as artificial or insincere; for non-native speakers, they are a mine field of assured self-destruction that may well get you sneered at or even punched in the face.
>
> Since so many of them are regional or from one particular subculture, whenever someone with an accent other than the region they come from uses one of these, it sounds fake. Fake is bad.
>
> You have been warned. Just don’t do it.

Comment: I would say that real men don’t _call them_ fems, because that’s a pretty derogatory term to use, but do talk to them, because there’s no reason not to that would fall under the category of bigotry that would automatically preclude them from being ‘real men’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Argh, you took *fems* to actually **mean** something! I thought it was just pineapple speech for humans of the feminine persuasion. Oops.

Comment: It is in actual usage, though not of a very nice kind (“No fats, no fems, no Asians” is probably the most well-known example of its usage). Clearly the asker thought it meant ‘women’, but I thought it prudent to let them know that it means something quite different!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My word...where on Earth do you find "no fats. no fems, no Asians". Is that from some Craig's list thingie?

Comment: @Cascabel Almost – you find more or less veiled versions of it on a disconcertingly high number of profiles on Grindr and all its siblings. Gay men can be terribly exclusionist pricks sometimes.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Live and learn. If a person is  advertising on Grindr, well, as I understand it it is pretty much only a "hook-up".  So they are looking for a type, and no complications. The wonders of (un)complicated relationships in the "modern" age.

Comment: @Cascabel Many people use it only for hookups; others use it for finding dates, relationships, or even friendships. Even for just hookups, though, it’s not a nice thing to say.

Comment: @Cascabel Well, that’s a new one to me, but it sounds like it might be – it’s simply a abbreviation of ‘feminine’ and refers to guys (and also girls, especially lesbians) who act in a stereotypically feminine way. For girls, it’s the opposite of _butch_; for guys, it’s the opposite of _masc_ (which is another epithet frequently touted in profile texts, often in the equally elitist form “masc for masc”, i.e., “I act in such a way that people rarely peg me as gay unless I tell them, and I’m only looking for guys who are the same”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, thank you. This has been a education. I have been out of that world in the US for almost 30 years, and most of my friends from there  dead from AIDS. Here, the culture is very underground; point in fact, the government is talking about making homosexuality illegal again. Incredible the differences in culture. Imagine if this were occurring in Saudi Arabia...

Comment: I remember “fem” being used in the 70s in a derogatory sense.

Comment: I assumed this was a mispelling of "femme", which I don't believe is offensive as long as you're actually referring to someone who identifies as feminine, or an abbreviation for "fembot", presuming OP often finds themselves in the company the company of humanoid robotic assassins.