# "Look, lady", "Listen, lady" – lady as a pejorative

Tags: etymology, linguistics, tone, sociolinguistics

This question is inspired by the wonderfully-named subreddit [r/IDontWorkHereLady](https://www.reddit.com/r/IDontWorkHereLady/).

When a proficient English speaker addresses someone as "lady" (as opposed to "ma'am"), it seems to often be used as a faux-polite way of expressing displeasure at someone's behavior. For example, a statement like "Lady, I think you need to stand in line over there" could suggest, "I'm upset that you were inconsiderate enough to cut in line".

1. I find it interesting that while the word "lady" by itself has a respectful connotation, it has gained the opposite connotation when used as an address. Does this kind of paradoxical semantic shift have a name? Is it a known linguistic phenomenon?
2. I'm also curious about the etymology of this usage. When did this shift in meaning come about, and what might have caused it?

   I tried searching Google Ngram Viewer for ["Look lady" and "Listen lady"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Look+lady%2CListen+lady&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=en-fiction-2019&smoothing=0), both capitalized so as to occur at the start of a sentence, with the hope that these ngrams would reflect the usage of "lady" in a derogatory/dismissive sense.

   [image: Google Ngram Viewer graph]

   It seems to have come into usage around 1950, and really took off in the late 1990s. I do wonder whether this simply reflects a change in the composition of Google's dataset (that is, an increase in informal speech in fiction writing), or whether real-world usage actually changed.

   Sampling usage on Google Books from different time periods, it seems that the meaning shifts subtly from informal neutral to derogatory:

   [Usage from 1940:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Argonauts/nAFLAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22look+lady%22&dq=%22look+lady%22&printsec=frontcover)

   > As we stood there, one of the newspapermen sauntered over and looked mournfully at the old lady. "Look, **lady**," he began, "I make only eighteen dollars a week. I'm only
   > twenty-six. and I've got to support a wife and two kids.

   [Usage from 1955:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cherry_Ames_Visiting_Nurse/I3fslAIczXQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22look+lady%22&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover)

   > "This can't be it!" Cherry said.
   >
   > The taxi driver turned around. "Look, **lady**. You give me an address, did'n' ya? I ain't responsible
   > for this here crazy Greenwich Village."
   >
   > Cherry alighted. She peered around, delighted and astonished, at the narrow crooked street and the ancient, little brick houses.
   >
   > "Seventy-five cents, **lady**."
   >
   > "Oh! Here you are." She paid him, then reached the cab for her suitcase.
   >
   > The taxi driver looked skeptically at the ten-cent tip she had given him. Then he studied Cherry, fresh-faced and trim, in her red suit and tiny black hat perched on
   > her black curls.
   >
   > "Look, **lady**. You ain't the Village type. You shoulda stood in Brooklyn. Like me."

   [Usage from 1970:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Making_of_a_Man/9x4SAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22look+lady%22&dq=%22look+lady%22&printsec=frontcover)

   > She replied, "Dr. Martin Luther King can follow Jesus's teachings, why can't you be as strong in faith as he is? Killing never solved any problems."
   >
   > I countered with, "Look, **lady**, those four little black kids killed last summer in Birmingham were in your Lord Jesus's sanctuary, a Christian Baptist church, and they were blown to bits by nice, white racist Christians.

   [Usage from 1990:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Miss_Manners_Guide_for_the_Turn_of_the_M/Ju1XvqoMookC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22look+lady%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)

   > "Look, **lady**, we're closing in fifteen minutes, and I'm not about to get involved in your transaction."

   [Usage from 2010:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Lady_Must_Decline/2V_JCzNQOwEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22look+lady%22&pg=PA7&printsec=frontcover)

   > The bartender glanced around, too, and leaned toward her, whispering, none too softly.
   >
   > "Look, **lady**, if you've got some kind of rendezvous, that ain't none of my business, I don't want to know, but that's what the back door is for."

   Anyways, this is what I found. I'd be curious about whatever details people can fill in on the etymology here.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is Lady? It isn't the sneering tone of Look and Listen, and the corresponding message of *You don't get it and need to listen up quick*? Look, darling, it could be the setup before the Lady part. And listen, my friend, you may be right anyway.

Comment: Similarly with "Sir" when it is plainly not said out respect. Not so much mocking, but stating the speaker is acting correctly.

Comment: NOAD labels this usage as "mainly North American" so not everyone may see this connotation, but it definitely exists.

Comment: Maybe there’s something here to inform your search? [Is there a word for colloquial forms of address?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334424/is-there-a-word-for-colloquial-forms-of-address)

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think adding Look or Listen definitely adds to the dismissiveness, but Lady still does the trick on its own – e.g. I was thinking of the magnificently-named subreddit [r/IDontWorkHereLady](https://www.reddit.com/r/IDontWorkHereLady/)! To be honest the reason I was using "Look, lady" in Google Ngrams/Books was because if I just search for "lady", I can't filter out only the usages where it's used as a direct address.

Comment: @JoLiss Yes, but are you sure you aren't reading pejoration in places where none is intended? Many of your examples to me read merely as informal means of address wherein substitution of the word "sir" fails the "pejoration smell test". Perhaps the issue at play here is more one of the apparent patriarchy (rightly) understood to underscore each example makes "lady" sound pejorative but not "sir". However the patriarchy is nothing new, not now or during any of the thens. It seems more reasonable to me to think that "lady" came to be used informally precisely from the fall of the bourgeois...

Comment: ... and the rise of the "middle class" in the English-speaking parts of the world, especially the USA and England.

Comment: I think it's a kind of sarcasm

Comment: I mean, *Look, Dude* sounds that way too. It seems to me that it’s the *look* part that makes it sound condescending. Try *Hey, Lady* instead and see if it still turns pejorative.

Comment: The word "sir" isn't the right comparison. Its pair in tone is "ma'am" or "madam". The word "lady", to me, has a negative tone, somewhere among disrespectful, contemptuous and sarcastic.

Comment: It's perhaps ironic politeness - if ma'am is the usual, then using something different will add emphasis, but a polite term can be used in a mocking/sarcastic way (as mentioned), such as addressing a person as "your majesty". It can indicate the person to whom you're speaking thinks they're special. Using "dude" is perhaps ironic familiarity, the opposite to ironic politeness but with the same effect.

Comment: _Mister_ can used that way also....

Comment: I agree with Tinfoil Hat: this is really just condescension, isn't it?

Comment: ***Hey, watch it lady!”***
You’ll never hear someone say “Hey, watch it gentleman!”

*Similarly there’s “young lady.” When a person uses lady in this context—a rude or offended tone—they’re indicating frustration with the woman receiver of the term. Using lady in this manner asserts the inherent meaning of the term, which suggests that the woman is causing irritation and should act in her “innate” polite manner.*

Instead of “lady,” you can use: jerk, fool, the name of the individual

Comment: There's also the consonance in "look lady" and "listen lady", which is missing in "look dude", etc. In countries where "lad" or "lass" is not uncommon I'd expect a similar use of "look lad" and "look lass".

Comment: My Dad used to say 'squire' in similar contexts. Like, arguing with another motorist. Maybe that's a male version. It implies respect, where there probably isn't any, in that exquisitely English way, of deeply insulting somebody while being ostensibly overly polite.

Comment: In British English I don't think you'd hear 'lady'. That would be perceived as rude  But you would hear 'madam...' or 'Sir!'.

Comment: Can we have a workable definition of 'English', please Jo Liss? As Jelila says, in British English 'lady' will normally be seen as rude; in much of Australia or US America, it won't. We Brits also 'Darling/Dear/Love' perfectly polite except when they're made perjorative by tone of voice but that's a different can of worms.

Answer (score 2):

The pejorative or sarcastic use is given as definition 3b in the AHD:

> Used as a form of address for a woman, often with sarcasm or irritation: Look, lady, I was ahead of you in line.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lady

Answer (score -1):

From my research it looks as though "lady" was originally pejorative . It's etymology is mostly hypothesized, but consensus puts emergence of the word circa 1200. The word lady shed its pejorative bonds and reemerged in the mid 1800s to denote a woman of higher social status.
Comparing the first known usage of lady to its counterpart lord:

The word 'lady'took on a negative connotation when it was first used in the mid 13th century-  pejoratively used to describe a lady as one who is a servant, as well as one who eats loaves.

OED says the ground sense of the ancient word 'lady' seems to be "kneader, maker of bread;" it would have then advanced via Old Norse deigja and Middle English daie to mean "female servant, woman employed in a house or on a farm." By c. 1200 it had acquired the specific sense of "woman in charge of milking and making butter and cheese, dairy-maid."

Lady(literally "bread-kneader"), and Old English hlafæta "household servant," literally "loaf-eater."
mid-13c.,
In contrast, the etymology of 'lord', the counterpart to 'lady', definitely has a far more positive connotation;

Lord, laverd, loverd, from Old English hlaford "master of a household, ruler, feudal lord, superior; husband," also "God," Old English hlaford is a contraction of earlier hlafweard, literally "one who guards the loaves," from hlaf "bread, loaf"

It is believed that the understanding of the status enjoyed by a 'lord' assisted the 'lady' in ascending to meet her counterpart.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This appears a skewed reading of the etymology. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=lady) paints a more flattering picture, "Sense of 'woman of superior position in society' is c. 1200; that of 'woman whose manners and sensibilities befit her for high rank in society' is from 1861 (ladylike suggesting this sense is attested from 1580s, and ladily from c. 1400). Meaning 'woman chosen as an object of chivalrous love' is from early 14c. Used commonly as an address to any woman since 1890s...Applied since Old English to the Holy Virgin" No mention of pejorative meaning.

Comment: @Samantha I don't have an OED subscription. Is there any chance you can cite the OED's etymology section in your answer?